# Error when I open AnySoftKeyboard

Tags: android, open-source

I import the project    https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard

and I face some errors like

```
import com.anysoftkeyboard.api.KeyCodes;
import com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard.R;
```

The import com.anysoftkeyboard.api cannot be resolved

and error
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'iconKeySpace'.

```
 <!-- should support normal, android:state_pressed, feedback, android:state_pressed+feedback, android:state_checked, state_checked+feedback -->
        <item name="iconKeyShift">@drawable/dark_key_shift_set</item>
        <!-- should support normal, android:state_pressed, feedback, android:state_pressed+feedback, android:state_checked, state_checked+feedback -->
        <item name="iconKeyControl">@drawable/dark_key_control_set</item>
        <!-- should support normal, feedback -->
        <item name="iconKeyBackspace">@drawable/dark_key_delete_set</item>
        <!-- should support normal, feedback -->
        <item name="iconKeySpace">@drawable/dark_key_space_set</item>
        <!-- should support normal, feedback -->
        <item name="iconKeyTab">@drawable/dark_key_tab_set</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add AnySoftKeyBoard-API project as libraries. You can download from this link.

> https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard-API